# More fields in React-admin login page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-admin

I need to insert one more field in the Login page, therefore, one other entry in the JSON login request and, although I managed to insert the field in the login page (as a `FormControl` with `Select`s), I'm having trouble in inserting the selected option into the JSON request.

`login.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { propTypes, reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';

import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import LockIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Lock';
import { MenuItem, Select, FormControl, InputLabel } from '@material-ui/core';

import { Notification, translate, userLogin } from 'react-admin';

import InstitutionSelect from "./InstitutionSelect";

const styles = theme => ({
    main: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        minHeight: '100vh',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        background: 'url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x900)',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
    },
    card: {
        minWidth: 300,
        marginTop: '6em',
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: '1em',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    icon: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    hint: {
        marginTop: '1em',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: theme.palette.grey[500],
    },
    form: {
        padding: '0 1em 1em 1em',
    },
    input: {
        marginTop: '1em',
    },
    actions: {
        padding: '0 1em 1em 1em',
    },
});

// see http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/material-ui/
const renderInput = ({
    meta: { touched, error } = {},
    input: { ...inputProps },
    ...props
}) => (
    <TextField
        error={!!(touched && error)}
        helperText={touched && error}
        {...inputProps}
        {...props}
        fullWidth
    />
);

class Login extends Component {
    login = auth =>
        this.props.userLogin(
            auth,
            this.props.location.state
                ? this.props.location.state.nextPathname
                : '/'
        );

    render() {
        const { classes, handleSubmit, isLoading, translate } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.main}>
                <Card className={classes.card}>
                    <div className={classes.avatar}>
                        <Avatar className={classes.icon}>
                            <LockIcon />
                        </Avatar>
                    </div>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.login)}>
                        <div className={classes.form}>
                            <div className={classes.input}>
                                <InstitutionSelect 
                                    name="institution"
                                    disabled={isLoading}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className={classes.input}>
                                <Field
                                    name="username"
                                    component={renderInput}
                                    label={translate('ra.auth.username')}
                                    disabled={isLoading}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className={classes.input}>
                                <Field
                                    name="password"
                                    component={renderInput}
                                    label={translate('ra.auth.password')}
                                    type="password"
                                    disabled={isLoading}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <CardActions className={classes.actions}>
                            <Button
                                variant="raised"
                                type="submit"
                                color="primary"
                                disabled={isLoading}
                                className={classes.button}
                                fullWidth
                            >
                                {isLoading && (
                                    <CircularProgress size={25} thickness={2} />
                                )}
                                {translate('ra.auth.sign_in')}
                            </Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </form>
                </Card>
                <Notification />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Login.propTypes = {
    ...propTypes,
    authProvider: PropTypes.func,
    classes: PropTypes.object,
    previousRoute: PropTypes.string,
    translate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    // Insert Institution here?
    userLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ isLoading: state.admin.loading > 0 });

const enhance = compose(
    translate,
    reduxForm({
        form: 'signIn',
        validate: (values, props) => {
            const errors = {};
            const { translate } = props;
            if (!values.institution) {
                errors.institution = translate('ra.validation.required');
            }
            if (!values.username) {
                errors.username = translate('ra.validation.required');
            }
            if (!values.password) {
                errors.password = translate('ra.validation.required');
            }
            return errors;
        },
    }),
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        { userLogin }
    ),
    withStyles(styles)
);

export default enhance(Login);
```

`authProvider.js`:

```
import { AUTH_LOGIN, AUTH_LOGOUT, AUTH_ERROR, AUTH_CHECK } from 'react-admin';

export default (type, params) => {
    // called when the user attempts to log in
    if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
        const { institution, username, password } = params;
        localStorage.setItem('username', username);
        const request = new Request('194.117.29.119:3000/api/users/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ 
                institution,
                username, 
                password 
            }),
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        })
        return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(({ token }) => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            });
    }
    // called when the user clicks on the logout button
    if (type === AUTH_LOGOUT) {
        localStorage.removeItem('username');
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    // called when the API returns an error
    if (type === AUTH_ERROR) {
        const { status } = params;
        if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
            localStorage.removeItem('username');
            return Promise.reject();
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    // called when the user navigates to a new location
    if (type === AUTH_CHECK) {
        return localStorage.getItem('username')
            ? Promise.resolve()
            : Promise.reject();
    }
    return Promise.reject('Unknown method');
};
```

`InstitutionSelect.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MuiThemeProvider from "@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import { InputLabel, FormControl } from "@material-ui/core";

const styles = theme => ({
    fullWidth: {
        width: "100%"
    }
});

class InstitutionSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectOptions: [
                {
                    value: "blablabla",
                    id: "1"
                },
            ],
            selectedValue: "",
        };
    }

    renderSelectOptions = () => {
        return this.state.selectOptions.map((option, i) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
                {option.value}
            </MenuItem>
        ));
    };

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ selectedValue: event.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;

        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <FormControl className={classes.fullWidth}>
                    <InputLabel>Institution</InputLabel>
                    <Select value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={this.handleChange} >
                        {this.renderSelectOptions()}
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(InstitutionSelect);
```